# create a numpy matrix of with values in specific indexes

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

```
arr = np.zeros(5)
indexes = np.array([1, 3])
values = np.array([10, 20])
arr[indexes] = values
```

so I get this array:

```
>>> arr
array([ 0., 10.,  0., 20.,  0.])
```

If I would like to have the following matrix:

```
>>> mat
array([[ 1,  0,  2,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  3,  0,  4,  0],
       [ 0,  5,  0,  0,  6],
       [ 7,  0,  8,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  9,  0,  0, 10]])
```

I tried to use this code:

```
mat = np.zeros((5, 5))
indexes = np.array([[0, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [0, 2], [1, 4]])
values = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]])
```

When I try to execute this code:

```
mat[indexes] = values
```

I get the following error:

`ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (5,2) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (5,2,5)`

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the row and column for slicing a matrix

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.zeros((5, 5))
indexes = np.array([[0, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [0, 2], [1, 4]])
values = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]])

for row_i, column_indices in enumerate(indexes):
    mat[row_i, column_indices] = values[row_i]

print(mat)
>> array([[ 1.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  3.,  0.,  4.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  5.,  0.,  0.,  6.],
          [ 7.,  0.,  8.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  9.,  0.,  0., 10.]])
```

Or without a for loop to assign values:

```
rows = np.indices((mat.shape[0],)).reshape(-1, 1)
mat[rows, indexes] = values
print(mat)
>> array([[ 1.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  3.,  0.,  4.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  5.,  0.,  0.,  6.],
          [ 7.,  0.,  8.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  9.,  0.,  0., 10.]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer
I can do it this way, but I prefer to do it without loops

Comment: See my edit for solution without for-loop

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [Numpy documentation on indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html) specifically Indexing Multi-dimensional arrays.

> What am I doing wrong?

```py
import numpy as np

mat = np.zeros((5, 5))
indexes = np.array([[0, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [0, 2], [1, 4]])
print(mat[indexes])
```

Which gives:

```
[[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]  # row 0
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]] # row 2

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]  # row 1
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]] # row 3

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]  # ...
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

You are then trying to assign your array of size `(5, 2)` to this slice, hence the mismatch error.

Solution:

```py
import numpy as np

mat = np.zeros((5, 5))
indicies = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]), np.array([0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 0, 2, 1, 4])
values = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
mat[indicies] = values
print(mat)
```

Which gives:

```
[[ 1.  0.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  3.  0.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  5.  0.  0.  6.]
 [ 7.  0.  8.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  9.  0.  0. 10.]]
```

To slice an array of size `(5, 5)` we can use two arrays. First array essentially represents the row index position, whilst the second essentially represents the column index position. This results in a slice of shape `(1, 10)` which we can assign our values to.

Comment: Although your solution works for this particular example, it is not really dynamic and usable for other (and larger) matrices

Comment: True, this method follows the form of OPs question though - asking "what am I doing wrong?"